# Blocking Android activity exit until cleanup finishes

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have a worker thread run by my activity. When exiting the activity (e.g. onPause()), I'm sending a message to this thread and it should finish shortly (milliseconds) after, unless something goes wrong.
Normally, I would use join() in onPause(), but in this case, this thread has to use the UI thread in order to perform its shutdown sequence (closing an Accessory file descriptor doesn't work from any other thread it seems).
So attempting to block the UI thread will cause a deadlock. I'm looking for a solution that will somehow postpone the app exit until after the thread exits.
Possibly, if I could just abort the exit in such a case, I could later call finish() manually, but I'm not sure whether this (aborting) can be done.

Just assuming that the thread will eventually finish its cleanup and exit seems like a very unsafe practice.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you cannot keep the UI thread waiting for the background thread to stop indefinitely.

You can do the following things.

1) Interrupt the thread in onPause().(This won't persist any info if you want during cleanup)

2)If you want to persist some information and perform a clean exit, you can start an Androiod service in onPause() and do the cleanup there.
(Check for a boolean flag timely inthe thread)
ex : A pseudo example

```
void run(){
while(true){
   if(bExit){
    doCleanupWork();
   }
  //Do work
  doWork();

  }
}

void doCleanupWork(){
startCleanupService();
}

void onPause(){
bExit = true;
}
```

## Edits

3)Override  onBackPressed() of Activity class so that it won't exit directly.Start an AsyncTask and show a dialog to the user indicating processing while cleanup calls occur in doInBackground() .If you are unsure that the cleanup might get hanged, you need to recheck the code and if required Interrupt the thread  after a timeout.

Comment: Performing the cleanup after the application exits is not the problem. The problem is postponing the application exit until the cleanup is complete.

Comment: Regarding (3): onBackPressed() is not the only situation when an app exits. Any attempt to cover all the possible exit paths, if at all possible, is very unreliable, un-portable and non-future-proof. As for the AsyncTask, this is completely unnecessary. Typically the cleanup will take milliseconds. I just want to catch any chance that it hangs and to make sure the app doesn't get restarted before completely cleaning up the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

declare a handler in the UI thread.  When the other thread has finished, send an (empty) message from the other thread to that handler, which will cause the handleMessage method to exectue on the UI thread.  Do your final UI cleanup in handleMessage.

Comment: But this will happen _after_ the `onPause()` or `onStop()` messages have already been handled, so the application has already exited, no? What I'm trying to achieve is delaying the application's exit until after the thread exits, but without blocking the UI thread on `join()` (as the part of the thread's cleanup involves doing work on the UI thread, and it'll cause a deadlock).

Comment: hmmmm -- I would feel comfortable simply telling a thread to shut down from onStop... I don't think there's any way to "abort" a shutdown anyway so all you can do is let the thread know to go through it's shutdown procedure.  Are you concerned that the thread may not cleanup completely?  It should be given the time to do what it needs to do (ie, the worker thread will not be killed immediately when the UI thread is complete).

Comment: I'm concerned about catching cleanup problems. I prefer getting an ANR than having a stuck thread lying around... Also, I want to make sure that the app doesn't get restarted before exiting cleanly. There are many situations where the app would get stopped / immediately restarted and that might cause problems.